# Multiple Averages and sum

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following objects in list (toInsertDatesRecords).

```
class SafeProtectDeviceReportUsage
{
    public long Vehicleid { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimestampLastConnection { get; set; }

    // Minutes
    public double AvgConnectionDuration { get; set; }
}
```

I need to return the average AvgConnectionDuration for all vehicles on a particular date (dd/MM).

Here is a data sample, many values for AvgConnectedDuration for the same vehicle.

| Date | VehicleId | AvgConnectedDuration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/02 | 1 | 302 |
| 05/02 | 1 | 1129 |
| 05/02 | 5 | 500 |
| 05/03 | 1 | 1440 |

The expected result is

| Date | count | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 05/02 | 2 | 302 + 1129 + 500 / 2 |
| 05/03 | 1 | 1440 / 1 |

I came with the following query:

```
var toBeReturned = toInsertDatesRecords.GroupBy(row => row.TimestampLastConnection.ToLocalTime().Date)
    .Select(g =>
    {
        int vCount = g.Select(c => c.Vehicleid).Distinct().Count();
        return new
        {
            date = g.Key.Date,
            count = vCount,
            duration = g.Average(c => c.AvgConnectionDuration)
        };
    });
```

It is wrong because I need to first sum the AvgConnectionDuration on a particular day for each vehicle before computing the average duration for all vehicles.

I can't figure out how to group by two times.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result for your question thank

Comment: @D-Shih I have added sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your sample data and expect results, you can try to use `Sum` and divide your count instead of using `Average`

```
var result = toInsertDatesRecords
    .GroupBy(row =>row.TimestampLastConnection.ToLocalTime().Date)
    .Select(g => 
    {
        int vCount = g.Select(c => c.Vehicleid).Distinct().Count();
        return new 
        {
            date = g.Key.Date,
            count = vCount,
            AvgConnectedDuration = g.Sum(x=> x.AvgConnectionDuration) / vCount
        };
    });
```

and I think we can use `g.GroupBy(x=>x.Vehicleid).Count()` count the number make it simple.

```
var result = toInsertDatesRecords
    .GroupBy(row =>row.TimestampLastConnection.ToLocalTime().Date)
    .Select(g => 
    {
        int vCount = g.GroupBy(x=>x.Vehicleid).Count();
        return new 
        {
            date = g.Key.Date,
            count = vCount,
            AvgConnectedDuration = g.Sum(x=> x.AvgConnectionDuration) / vCount
        };
    });
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pXXggS)

Comment: The result set should be {date, count, duration}. Provided the sample data contains another vehicle for the same date, duration is the average for both of them.

Comment: Hi @OlivierMATROT My answer depends on your sample data and expect result https://dotnetfiddle.net/  if that isn't your expected result could you modify your answer and provide sample data which can associate your logic and expected result?

Comment: Sorry about that, the expected result should be OK now.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT Ok I see I edited my answer hope that help

Comment: Excellent. I was not so far from it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
var toBeReturned = toInsertDatesRecords.GroupBy(row => row.TimestampLastConnection.ToLocalTime().Date)
    .Select(g => new {
            date = g.Key.Date,
            count = g.Select(c => c.Vehicleid).Distinct().Count(),
            duration = g.Average(c => c.AvgConnectionDuration)
        }
    ).select(g => new {date = g.date, count = g.Sum(h => h.count), duration = g,Average(h => h.count));
```

Comment: I've edited my question with sample data and expected result.